# How To Replace Variable Name To Variable Value In Swift?

Tags: swift, regex

I want to replace variable name between {{}} to its value, just like:
I can using Dictionary like:

```
//var a = 10
//var b = 20
var pairs:[string:int]=["a":10,"b":20]
var str = "I have {{a}} apples and {{b}} pears"
```

And Target is
"I have 10 apples and 20 pears"
How Can I Do It In Swift Using Regex?

Comment: Variable names are merely decorations for human convenience. They don't exist in your program at runtime, so there's no way to look up values by variable names. You're probably going to want to store the values in a dictionary, instead.

Comment: Is this some homework assignment?

Comment: What you want to do is : var str = "I have \\(pairs["a"]) apples and \\(pairs["b"])  pears"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexander notes, if you're trying to take an arbitrary String, read from outside the program, and apply substitutions based on variable names from inside the program, that's impossible in Swift. You need to store your data in a different way (such as a Dictionary). A library like [GRMustache](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache.swift) demonstrates one way this can be done, and handles specifically the kind of syntax you're describing.

However, if this String is known at compile-time, you can apply string interpolation to it:

```
var str = "I have \(a) apples and \(b) pears"
```

This is purely a compile-time feature. You cannot read a string formatted like this at runtime and have the substitutions appear. That would allow data to access the code, which is broadly not allowed in Swift.

---

With your Dictionary, you could implement it along these lines:

```
func replaceTokens<T>(in string: String, with pairs: [String: T]) -> String {
    
    // Regex for your tokens
    let regex = /{{([a-z]+)}}/
    
    // String to hold each part of the result
    var result = ""
    
    // Keep track of the current position in the input string.
    // This is used to copy out of the string
    var index = string.startIndex
    
    // Iterate through all matches of the regular expression in the input string.
    for match in string.matches(of: regex) {
        
        // Append the portion of the input string before the current match to the result.
        result += string[index..<match.range.lowerBound]
        
        // Update the index to the end of the current match.
        index = match.range.upperBound
        
        // Extract the token (key) from the matched substring.
        let key = match.1
        
        // Check for the token in the dictionary. Note that the results are Substrings,
        // so this needs to be converted to a string to be used as a dictionary key.
        // If there's no value for this token, it is removed. You could choose instead
        // to copy it as-is.
        if let value = pairs[String(key)] {
            result += "\(value)"
        }
    }
    
    // Append the remaining portion of the input string to the result.
    result += string[index..<string.endIndex]
    return result
}

var pairs:[String:Int]=["a":10,"b":20]
var str = "I have {{a}} apples and {{b}} pears"

replaceTokens(in: str, with: pairs)
```

Comment: If I can store variables into dictionary, can i using regex to replace? Thank you!